# In 1 Corinthians 3:22 what does Paul mean by "you are of Christ and Christ is of God"?

Tags: 1-corinthians

> NIV 1 Corinthians 3:21
>
> So then, no more boasting about human leaders! All things are yours, 22 whether Paul or Apollos or Cephas or the world or life or death or the present or the future—all are yours, 23 and **you are of Christ, and Christ is of God**.

Comment: ***Of God*** translates into Latin as [*Deus Ex*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_Ex), not to be confused with [*Deus ex machina*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina), though [Jerry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome) prefers [*autem*](http://www.biblestudytools.com/vul/1-corinthians/3-23.html).

Comment: Does autem still mean https://translate.google.com/?hl=en#view=home&op=translate&sl=la&tl=en&text=autem

Comment: It is both related and pronounced similarly to the English *out*.

Comment: "you come from God"?

Comment: *Out of God*, yes.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think that definitely belongs in the "stew".

Comment: Wasn't the meaning of the Latin *ex* mentioned earlier transparent from that of the English word *exit*, for instance ?

Comment: Yes. I was asking about "autem" for which Google Translate has "but"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92798/discussion-between-ruminator-and-lucian).

Comment: They are equivalent. The *aut-* in *autem* corresponds to the English *out*, and the Latin *ex* mirrors the Greek *ek*, albeit the quoted passage has *de* rather than *ek*. (Feel free to move it to chat entirely; it's all a bunch of silly trivia anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is hinting at Christ's coming to do the will of God. He was and is still devoted to the service of his Father. God has a proprietorship in all that he does, since Christ lived, and acted, and reigns to promote the glory of his Father.

> John 4:34
>   Jesus said to them, “My food is to do the will of him who sent me and to accomplish his work."
>
> John 6:38
>   "For I have come down from heaven, not to do my own will but the will of him who sent me."

The argument here seems to be this, 'You belong to Christ; and he to God. You are bound therefore, not to devote yourselves to a man, whoever he may be, but to Christ, and to the service of that one true God, in whose service even Christ was employed. And as Christ sought to promote the glory of his Father, so should you in all things.'

> 1 Corinthians 10:31
>   So, whether you eat or drink, or whatever you do, do all to the glory of God.
>
> Ephesians 4:20-22
>   20 But that is not the way you learned Christ!— 21 assuming that you have heard about him and *were taught in him, as the truth is in Jesus*, 22 to put off your old self, which belongs to your former manner of life and is corrupt through deceitful desires, (emphasis added)

Verses are from ESV

Comment: I don't know how to indent with the yellow highlight, so I'm hoping by adding spaces between paragraphs it is still easy to read.

Comment: Hi Josh and welcome to the site. I did the formatting for you. If you hit the **edit** button under the words "Verses are from ESV" you can see what I did. Nice answer. +1

Comment: Hello, Ruminator. I saw what symbol to use to do that kind of formatting when I checked how my answer was edited. Thanks for your formatting and feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is the contrast Paul makes in the previous discussion about factionalism.  Some claimed to be "of Apollos", or, "of Cephas", or, "of Paul" (1 Cor 1:11, 12, 3:4, etc).  That is, such people follow the teachings and leadership of their chosen "groupie" (to use a modern term).

Paul draws this section of ant-factionalism to a conclusion by effectively suggesting two things:

- We all should follow (be "of") Christ
- Since Christ of "of God" that this is a much higher (better) group to be part of than mere humans.  The NIV & NRSV imply this same idea in their rendering of 1 Cor 3:21-23, "no more boasting about human leaders … you are of Christ and Christ is of God".

Comment: Hi Mac. Can you please clarify what it means to be "of Apollos"?

Comment: Presumably "of Paul" means "belonging to the group or faction which follows the leadership and teachings of Paul."

Comment: That is how I understand it.  It appears that the phenomenon was as common then as now.  The Greek construction is a simple genitive: some versions translate, "of Apollos", others, "belonging to Apollos".  Both are grammatically correct.  Both imply a faction that supposedly confers status on the adherents.

Comment: Thanks, but then how do you make it parallel or rather read it parallel with you are of Christ and Christ is of God?

Comment: @Ruminator - I am not sure I understand your question here.  What is "make it parallel"?  The Bible calls Christians "Children of God" (Rom 8:14, Gal 3:26, Phil 2;15, etc) as opposed to "sons of the devil" (John 8:44, Eph 2:2).  In this sense, Christ is our brother (Heb 2:11-13, Matt 12:48, 49, John 20:17, Rom 8:29).

Comment: So is Christ "belonging to the group or faction which follows the leadership and teachings of God"?

Comment: That is the implication

Comment: So is Christ "belonging to the group or faction which follows the leadership and teachings of God"? Basically, "of Paul" isn't really English. You wouldn't say, "I'm of John Piper". It would not mean anything to the hearer! Can you translate it into English?

Comment: You might say that is not good English but I have heard it many times amongst modern "groupies".  W hear it in various guises such as " I am a Calvinist", or, "I am a Lutheran", essentially meaning that such people follow the teachings of these people.  That is "Calvinist" means, "of Calvin".  "Paul-ist" or "Apollo-ist" is awkward in English.